# On the pronunciation of 's' in 'dislike' (/s/ vs /z/)

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, phonetics

With a bit of a surprise I have recently learnt that most(all?) native English speakers pronounce the 's' in *dislike* (and similar words with the *dis-* prefix) as /s/, not /z/.

However, the /z/ variant also seems to exist, as a quick Google search by the ["dizlike" pronunciation](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=opera&biw=1880&bih=938&ei=zob7XZviJYvzgQbysp6IDg&q=%22dizlike%22+pronunciation&oq=%22dizlike%22+pronunciation&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13j0i13i30.15128.19295..23507...0.0..0.95.1354.18......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i10j33i160j0i22i30j0i8i13i30.Nm2bO9PvsHo&ved=0ahUKEwibgfnt88HmAhWLecAKHXKZB-E4PBDh1QMICg&uact=5) keywords has shown.

One of the links from the above search results leads to the following text from *A Pronouncing and Defining Dictionary of the English Language* abridged from *Webster* in 1856:

```
§ 70. S unmarked has its regular sharp or hissing 
sound, as in same, gas, mass, &c. 
§ 71. S, when marked thus, $, s, has the sound of 
z hard, as in has, xoas, &c. 
Note. — There has been much diversity between 
orthoepists as to the sound of s in words commencing 
in dis, as disarm, disburse, &c. Walker laid down 
this rule: "It (s) ought always to be pronounced 
like z when unaccented, and followed by an ac- 
cented flat mute (b, d, g hard, v), a liquid (I, m, 
n, r), or a vowel." Hence he gave pronunciation 
like the following, disbud, dizbud; disedify, diz- 
edify; disjoin, dizjoin; dislike, dizlike; dislodge,         <-- dizlike
cfelodge, &c. Scarcely any subsequent orthoepist 
has gone so far. Webster's Dictionary gives s the 
sound of z in only the following words, viz., dis- 
arm, disaster, discern, disease, disheir, dishonest, 
dishonor, dismal, disown, dissolve. The Imperial, 
Craig, and Wright agree almost to a word with 
Webster. Perry and Knowles give the z sound 
even in fewer words ; Smart gives it in about eight 
more; Jameson and Boag go still further; but, with 
one or two exceptions, the orthoepists as a body 
have condemned the extent to which Walker has 
gone in this respect.
```

[Source](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdefin00webs/pronouncingdefin00webs_djvu.txt)

So far, I failed to find any information on (**and this is essentially my question:**) whether this peculiarity (using the /z/ sound in *dislike*) can be attributed to a particular region, background or anything of that sort, or is it just some sort of a personal preference?

So I'm asking the community for some help with this matter.

**Edit**
A bit more on what lead me to believe that the 'dizlike' pronunciation exists:

[David Hart](https://www.f6s.com/davidhart) [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/DavidHart/status/1050461894803361792):
"I dislike it when people pronounce dislike as though it is spelt dizlike."

Judging from the initial comments, though, it looks like English speakers strongly disagree with the very possibility of using /z/ in *dislike*. Other than to mock a foreign accent, I presume.

What would be the explanation of the quoted text, then? (The one provided as an image). Yes, I realise that the date is 1856 - does this mean the /z/ pronunciation existed at that time but completely disappeared by now? Or is it just a dictionary mistake and should be ignored?

**Edit 2**
Transcriptions of *dislike* in most popular dictionaries:

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/dislike_2): NOUN  /dɪsˈlaɪk/

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dislike): UK /dɪˈslaɪk/ US /dɪˈslaɪk/

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dislike): dis·​like | \ (ˌ)dis-ˈlīk  , ˈdis-ˌlīk \

Pronunciation examples on [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/dislike/) - 5 recordings by native speakers.

Comment: I've never noticed anyone saying "dislike" with a "z" sound and would consider it unusual.

Comment: Why do you think pronouncing an *s* with an *s* sound is a peculiarity? Why did you expect a *z* sound?

Comment: Indeed, in words that contain the prefix "dis", "dis" is always pronounced with /s/, regardless of the following sound. ("Disease" is now treated as if it were a single morpheme rather than a compound of *dis-* and *ease*, so it's really not an exception; likewise *dissolve*. Were *disaster* and *dismal* ever thought to be compounds of *dis-*, I wonder -- they certainly aren't now.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm calling the /z/ pronunciation a peculiarity.

Comment: @nnnnnn "Why did you expect a z sound?" - some foreigners (including myself until recently) pronounce it with /z/ because in their native language there is a "phonetic rule" that /s/ in front of a voiced consonant *tends* to turn into the voiced /z/. It is not a universal rule, though, and /s/ in front of an /l/ is a bit of a corner case.

Comment: There are probably over a billion speakers of English, so any statement of the form "`X` is always pronounced `Y`" is bound to be false. Nothing is **always** pronounced in any particular way. There are standards, but local speech groups vary widely, and so do individuals, from moment to moment. Some people automatically voice all consonants in a cluster, and some don't; some people take account of the juncture between _dis-_ and _like_, and others don't.

Comment: For the data, 'dis' before voiced, I used "grep -E '^dis[bdglmnvaeiou]' /usr/share/dict/words" and my own pronunciation. Only 'dismal' has a voiced 's'; those left all seem to be 'dis-' as a prefix and I pronounce the 's' unvoiced. Maybe 'disgust' for me has the first 's' sometimes voiced. But that's about it.

Comment: I love Forvo, but it is not comprehensive at all (doesn't sample varieties (UK vs US vs Can vs Aus etc etc), no indication of popularity), only those people who bother to submit are represented. Think of it as a source for confirmation ('voice #3 sounds exactly like me') but not for counterexamples (ie you can't deduce that no one says it ---the way you do--- 'right' if none of the three or four versions sounds like what you expect).

Comment: @Mitch Have you considered compiling an answer? It becomes more and more difficult to fetch anything solid from all these, rather contradicting, comments. Your personal view on the topic would be valuable. I, in my turn, will try to re-read all the input and think whether I shall rephrase my question and in what way.   I can now see that some readers seem to misunderstand the question.

Comment: @Mitch See also: my answer.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/531695/365490): about the pronunciation of 'dis-'.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Thanks. Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

From a bit of research online, it appears that the pronunciation /dɪzˈlaɪk/ is essentially **teutonic** (found in Celtic, Scottish dialects, OE) and is considered **archaic** today.

Sources suggest it was the official pronunciation in the 1800s:

- **1805**: Stephen Jones, "A General Pronouncing and Explanatory Dictionary of the English Language," (Vernor & Hood), London.
- **1818**: John Walker, "A Critical Pronouncing Dictionary, and Expositor of the English Language," (Ambrose Walker), Philadelphia.
- **1847**: William James, "Dictionary of the English and French Languages for General Use," (B. Tauchnitz, Leipzig).
- **1872**: William A. Wheeler, "A dictionary of the English language, … Mainly abridged from the quarto dictionary of Noah Webster," Springfield, Mass.

Comment: “dɪsˈlaɪk” is not archaic. It’s the pronunciation given by Merriam-Webster: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dislike I also don’t understand why Celtic would be described as “Teutonic”

Comment: @herisson Lol !!

Answer (score -1):

I understand why you think it should be pronounced with z, (as in BrE the spelling for words differs from AmE in some words e.g. organise, trivialise, but pronunciation remains the same), but for the prefix "dis" we always remain at /s/.

Notice the year of your source material (PHILADELPHIA. 1856.), it's a very archaic work.

Comment: No, no - I do not think *it should* be pronounced with /z/. The modern dictionaries clearly give the /s/ in the transcription. But the Google search shows that the pronunciation 'dizlike' does exist (or at least *did* exist) - hence the question.

Comment: Not *all* words starting with *dis-* have it pronounced /s/. *Disease*, *dismal*, *dissolve*, *disaster* all have the /z/ pronunciation in my own (fairly standard Canadian) accent. (A minority, to be sure, as most other words do take /s/!) To my ear, using /s/ in these would be acceptable but marked, as if from a foreign (but still native-speaking English) accent or done to sound posh.

Comment: @Mitch *I'm going to delete these comments in a while...* On the other hand, I've just re-read the [Help/On-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page and my question seems to be OK for this place. Pronunciation and *dialectology* are mentioned as on-topic, the history of language is presented by *Etymology* only but I believe the history of pronunciation changes can hardly be seen as off-topic.